# Small letters in PROMPT param in as400

Tags: ibm-midrange, ibm-integration-bus, ibm-ifs

I had command file -

```
 CMD PROMPT('MY COMMAND FILE')                                     
 PARM KWD(A1) TYPE(*CHAR) VALUES(A1 A2) LEN(11) MIN(1) +    
 PROMPT('MY NAME IS ANDY') RSTD(*YES)                                           
 PARM KWD(A2) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(250) MIN(1) +                                  
 PROMPT('MY NAME IS BRAWO')
```

I want to add small letters in PROMPT('my name is andy') param.
I tryied to create command file with small letter description but its not allowing me to do so.

Comment: What does "not allowing me to do so" mean?  What error message are you seeing?

Comment: Is this press F13 allow lower case *yes.   or prompt the command F4 and enter the lower case stuff?

Comment: Thnx danny. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

You can put lower case letters in quotes. If you just key lowercase letters, they are automatically converted to upper case, but anything inside the quotes is kept as is.

```
CMD PROMPT('MY COMMAND FILE')                                     
PARM KWD(A1) TYPE(*CHAR) VALUES(IdentityIQ IdentityNow) LEN(11) MIN(1) +    
PROMPT('My name is Andy') RSTD(*YES)                                           
PARM KWD(A2) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(250) MIN(1) +                                  
PROMPT('My name is Brawo')
```

Now if you are using RDi, you might have a setting to auto uppercase everything. I don't think it upper cases anything in quotes, but if you are having trouble with that you can fix the setting in RDi.